# Access auto-assigning Null to non-Variant--where?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

In Access 2007, I have two tables related such that the (surrogate) PK of one is an FK in the other:

```
table Organization (
     org_id       int PK,
     other_fields whatever,
     contact_id   int FK
 )

table contact (
    contact_id     int PK,
    contact_nm     text(255),
    other_fields   whatever
)
```

Obviously not complete table definitions....

So I build forms that reflect this--there's a frmOrganization, with a subform sbfContact. They're related by contact_id, just as the tables are. There are controls on sbfContact for all fields in table contact *except* contact_id (though it is, of course, present in the Record Source (SELECT * FROM contact;)). Neither form has any code that references the other in any way, and no macros at all.

My problem occurs when I try to use the subform to enter a new contact. As soon as I type a character into the control bound to contact_nm, Access tells me that "You tried to assign the Null value to a variable that is not a Variant data type." I what? Where? I'm not assigning *anything* to *any* variable--am I? If I answer "OK" to the message, the character I just typed appears in the control & everything proceeds as I expect.

What's going on here, and--more importantly--what do I need to do to make it stop?

**Edit with more info**

Okay, I was hoping to simplify, but I don't s'pose it helped.... What I really have is four different entities that each requires its own Contact data:

```
Customer
Site

Manufacturer

Engineer
```

(The line spacing is significant--a Customer will have at least one Site, maybe more, but Sites can exist without Customers (unless I carry "us" as a Customer). The other two are totally independent).

I observed the original problem working with one of the "master" entites, and figured that it would be parallel in the others. I think that CodeSlave has pointed me to the correct source of the problem--I'm afraid that my only recourse is to not allow additions through this subform, instead building a freestanding "Create Contact" form. Other suggestions are welcome, though....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Access has no idea how to link your Contact to the Org, it's assuming that you already know what the Contact_ID is because it's coming from the Org form, but it's still Null when you enter the Contact on the subform.

I think you want to flip things around here.

Have you got a `Contact with multiple Orgs` or an `Org with multiple Contacts`.

In the case of a `Contact with multiple Orgs`, make the Contact the master form, and the Org the sub form.

In the case of an `Org with multiple Contacts`, give the Contact a FK to the Ord_ID and drop the Contact_ID from the Org

--

Follow up based upon the comment.

The way I would deal with the same contact being used for multiple entities, I wouldn't make the contact entry on a sub form. Instead I would create the comments on a completely different form, and then select the contacts with a pull down list (and just display the rest of the contact info on the Org's form).  Even if you have to have a "create contact" button on your Org form to pup up a create form temporarily, you'll get more bang for your buck.

Comment: Aha! I think I understand the problem now, but the situation is actually more complex. I have four different entities that will each have Contacts associated with them--and yes they're _really_ different. In fact, two of those have a parent/child relationship between them (but each needs its own Contact data, since it may or may not be the same). I don't think I can implement either of your suggested fixes, but I should be able to make my forms workable. If I don't get an even-better suggestion within a week I'll accept your answer.